# Can I run ASP.NET 4.0 App in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I had been using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.. Recently I have updated my OS to Windows 8 now I am planning to install Visual Studio 2012.. I have many ASP.NET Classic Form project which are build in .Net 4.0 ... I want to know if I can use/develop those projects on VS 2012 using .Net Framework 4.0?

Comment: This has been asked a gazillion times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio 2012 can be used to develop apps targeting .NET 2.0 -> .NET 4.5.

Note that for .NET 4.0 apps, you'll actually be running on .NET 4.5 (built-in to Win8, or installed with VS2012 on Win7).  However, the differences should be imperceptible.